# Why use a using statement with a SqlTransaction?

Tags: c#, using-statement, sqltransaction, system.data, system.data.sqlclient

I've been running into some problems concerning a SqlTransaction I'm using in my code. During my Googling I see many people using a using statement with a SqlTransaction.

What is the benefit and/or difference of using this type of statement with a SqlTransaction?

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
{
     using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())
     {
      //some code
      tr.Commit();
     }
}
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["T3"]);
cn.Open();
SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction();

try
{
     //some code
     tr.Commit();
     cn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
      tr.Rollback();
      cn.Close();
      throw ex;
}
```

What is the advantage of one way over the other?

Comment: For "less" nesting, I believe you can skip the first pair of curly brackets. (or is it braces...)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A `using` statement should be used every time you create an instance of a class that implements `IDisposable` *within the scope of a block*. It ensures that the `Dispose()` method will be called on that instance, whether or not an exception is thrown.

In particular, your code only catches managed exceptions, then destroys the stack frame by throwing a new exception instead of rethrowing the existing one.

The correct way to do it is:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["T3"])) {
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction()) {
        //some code
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

Note that if your class has instance members of types that implement `IDisposable`, then your class must implement `IDisposable` itself, and dispose of those members during its own `Dispose()` call.

Comment: ....because it guarantees that the "Dispose" method of the IDisposble interface being implemented will be called - no matter what happens in your code.

Comment: +1, generally correct, but you can't _always_ use a using statement, sometimes you need to implement IDisposable yourself. I would say: "Whenever possible", which means "whenever creating an IDisposable instance used only within a bloc" or something like this.

Comment: That makes sense. I've also corrected my exception. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, if `Dispose` is called on the `SqlTransaction` before a `Commit`, then the transaction will be rolled back. Of course, `Dispose` will be called if an exception is thrown within the block and not handled.

Comment: Do we have to explicitly declare tran.rollBack() inside a catch or will this be handled by the using block?

Comment: @ZoHas it will be handled in the Dispose

Comment: I think we still need to add Rollback in catch so as to make sure we Rollback immediately and not wait for GC.

Comment: @Mukus you won't need to call `Rollback` explicitly. If the transaction hasn't been committed by the time that `Dispose` is called, then `Rollback` will be called for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders But the point is it will not get called immediately.

Comment: @Mukus yes, it will be called immediately, at the end of the `using` block. The end of the `using` block calls the `Dispose` method. If the `Dispose` method sees that the transaction has not been committed or rolled back, then it will immediately call the `Rollback` method.

Answer (score 30):

The reason for this is that the SqlTransaction object will roll back in its Dispose() method if it was not explicitly committed (e.g. if an exception is thrown). In other words, it has the same effect as your code, just a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Confirmed this by de-compiling. Calls this.Rollback() on this.Dispose().

Comment: Actually, whether or not Rollback is called inside Dispose() dependent on the implementation of the driver you're using (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2cw321(v=vs.110).aspx). Driver implementors are supposed to call Rollback, but Microsoft recommends not counting on it. So if you know the only driver you'll ever use does call Rollback inside Dispose() you're safe. Otherwise, it's safer to explicitly call it.

Answer (score 16):

Essentially the using does the same thing that you are doing, except int a finally block instead of catching all exceptions:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
{
     using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())
     {
      //some code
      tr.Commit();
     }
}
```

is the same as, just much less code :)

```
{
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    try
    {
       cn = new SqlConnection();
       {
           SqlTransaction tr = null;
           try
           {
               tr = cn.BeginTransaction())

               //some code
               tr.Commit();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(tr != null && tr is IDisposable)
                {
                    tr.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cn != null && cn is IDisposable)
        {
            cn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually have an extra set of braces in your first example:  you can nest using statements without creating a new block, e.g. `using (x = new X) using (y = new Y) { }`

Comment: Just being explicit, same reason we always put braces around all our if statements, even if they're one-liners

Comment: You should also do `cn.Open();` before `using (SqlTransaction tr ...`. Otherwise you will receive InvalidOperationException. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

In the end, `using` is just a shortcut for a pattern.  But it's a very *useful* and helpful shortcut, because it ensures you implement the pattern correctly and means you can do it with less code.

In this case, you haven't implemented the pattern correctly.  What happens in your code if the call to `tr.RollBack()` also throws an exception?

Answer (score 4):

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is closing and disposing your connection and transaction for you.  It's the equivalent of having a finally block on your try/catch that does the dispose.

You could also condense the using blocks down a bit like this...

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())     
{
      //some code
      tr.Commit();
}
```

which would be roughly the same as:

```
SqlConnection cn = null;
SqlTransaction tr = null;
try
{
    cn = new SqlConnection());
    tr = cn.BeginTransaction());

    //some code
    tr.Commit();
}
finally
{
    if (cn != null)
        cn.Dispose();
    if (tr != null)    
        tr.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Very close, but there's also an additional anonymous scope block in there.  The code as you have it won't compile, because cn and tr are out of scope in the finally block.

Comment: @ZoHas it will automatically Rollback at `Dispose();` if there was none call of `Commit();` [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/641669/1993545)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use a using() block, you'll have to explicitly call the .Dispose() method of the SqlConnection and SqlTransaction objects.  If you fail to do that, then unmanaged resources will not be released and could cause memory leaks or other problems.

Comment: Would not cause memory leaks, but it might cause resource leaks.

Comment: ... which will efff you worse and faster.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all that, it prettifies your code. Doesn't the 7 lines of code look better than the 14 lines? I breath a sign of relief every time I see a using block. It's like that little squirt of mist that comes out of that glad smelly thing. Mmm, I'm a pretty block of efficient code. Look at how well I manage memory and how pleasing I am to the eye.

Answer (score 1):

Using using gurantees that your connection object will be disposed after the code returns. Dispose is useful to release unmanages resources, As a good practice, if an object implements IDisposable, dispose method always should be called

Comment: Connection - and the SqlTransaction object.

Comment: If an object implements `IDisposable`, then a `using` block (or statement) should be used, which guarantees that `Dispose` will be called.