# c# ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having the same error i see multiple threads having, after googling for 2 days i cannot seem to fix the issue and i am failing to see why. I simplified some of the code that did not pertain to the sqltransaction portion.

```
    conn.Open();

using (SqlTransaction sqlTran = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", conn, sqlTran);
    log.Info("Connection Opened");


    foreach (var eventData in reqData)
    {
        ProcessMessage(eventData, req, conn, log, sqlTran, command);
    }

    sqlTran.Commit();
    sqlTran.Dispose();
}
conn.Close();

public static void ProcessMessage(JObject messageData, HttpRequestMessage req, SqlConnection conn, TraceWriter log, SqlTransaction sqlTran, SqlCommand command)
{
        //query building stuff
        PerformTransaction(req, query, conn, log, sqlTran, command);
}

public static void PerformTransaction(HttpRequestMessage req, string query, SqlConnection conn, TraceWriter log, SqlTransaction sqlTran, SqlCommand command)
{
     try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            log.Info("Query Executed Successfully");
        }
     catch
        {
            log.Info("Transaction Execution Error");
            sqlTran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: Given that your error message mentions `ExecuteReader` I am inclined to think that the problem is not in this block of code as there is no call to `ExecuteReader`. Perhaps you are calling it elsewhere in the same transaction but forgot to set the sqlTran on the command object?

Comment: It was this, i cannot mark a comment as an answer but our talk did help me organize my code better also.

Comment: I am glad to be of assistance. For info, your original set of statements are perfectly fine for the multiple inserts in one transaction. I have used a similar method for inserts, deletes and updates

Answer (score 1):

<s>You forgot to add `command.Transaction = sqlTran;` right before you `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` in your `PerformTransaction()`.</s>

```
public static void PerformTransaction(HttpRequestMessage req, string query, SqlConnection conn, TraceWriter log, SqlTransaction sqlTran, SqlCommand command)
{
     try
        {
            command.Transaction = sqlTran;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            log.Info("Query Executed Successfully");
        }
     catch
        {
            log.Info("Transaction Execution Error");
            sqlTran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** Actually your problem is that you are trying to use the same `sqlTran` for multiple transactions when the first transaction that `sqlTran` did has not finished yet. In other words, You have started another transaction that is not commited before you called `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Try moving your `sqlTran.Commit()` to be inside the `try` block after you `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` in your `PerformTransaction()`. That way, the current transaction get's commited before you try to execute another.

```
public static void PerformTransaction(HttpRequestMessage req, string query, SqlConnection conn, TraceWriter log, SqlTransaction sqlTran, SqlCommand command)
{
     try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            log.Info("Query Executed Successfully");
            sqlTran.Commit();
            log.Info("Transaction Commited Successfully");
        }
     catch
        {
            log.Info("Transaction Execution Error");
            sqlTran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: didn't he specify the transaction in the constructor of the command though?

Comment: @Cato Just noticed.

Comment: is the tran and connection properly connected?  It would be possible to pass just tran and get connection from tran.connection property.  Are nested transactions possible?  (sorry never used them)

Comment: my goal is to have multiple transactions and if any of them failed to roll them all back, is this not possible?

Comment: @user1552172 Yes, just create multiple transactions and call them all. Instead of using the same Transaction. If they all run successfully then you can commit them all.

Comment: Interesting, i will give that a shot.

Comment: @user1552172 running multiple commands in a single transaction is EXACTLY the way you want to be going as per your description. Either all commit, or all fail. Perhaps clarify if you mean a Business Transaction or Database transaction.

Comment: database, i have maybe 10 sql statements at once (varies) that i want to successfully happen before committing. How would i do this @JayV i had the same thought that multiple could run but the error says otherwise :(

Comment: @user1552172 Use a single SqlTransaction then. See this question/answer for guidance on this one point. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019525/9365244. And, please see my comment on your question.

Comment: @JayV ill get it like the link and see if it works, and i am using execute reader in one spot....thats most likely it. i did not see your comment sorry.