# Multiple instances of a C# Application updating a single MSSQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have several instances of our application running at the same time at various places.

And all instances execute an `insert or update` query on a single table `Orders`.

```
Orders
---------------------------------------

OrderID OrderDate OrderTime OrderAmount
```

The question is, if all instances of my application `insert or update` records at the same time, what might happen?

How does MSSQL database handle this scenario?

I googled out and found `ROWLOCK, XLOCK, READPAST` as a solution on `concurrent access to MSSQL database` ***but could not find an exact answer for the above scenario!***

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: You can use the SQLTransaction Class like this: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127839/809613

Comment: You can use the SQLTransaction Class like [this:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127839/809613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will run in an (implicit) transaction such that the statements will be queued. This should normally not be a problem.

If the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements are part of a batch with other statements which need to be run uninterrupted (such as first reading from a table, then updating the table based on the result), you should consider enclosing these statements in an explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx). This will enable you to avoid any data corruption which will occur from your current setup.