# how to pass parameter to oracle function within c# environment

Tags: c#, oracle

I search on the net to execute oracle stored function and get the value of it 
and I found something similar to this but i don't really understand it so i am not able to find out what's the error with it... please if someone can explan 
whats happening after opening the connection with the database ?

```
public void Get_Office_Desc()
{
    string oradb = "Data Source=mysource;User Id=emp;Password=00;";
    var v_Office_code = Current_Office_code.Text;
    string CommandStr = "F_Get_Office_Desc(:pOfficeCode)";

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pOfficeCode", v_Office_code));
        cmd.Parameters.Add("pOfficeDesc", OracleType.Char, 128);
        cmd.Parameters["pOfficeDesc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var pOfficeDesc = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["pOfficeDesc"].Value);

        messagebox.show(pOfficeDesc);
    }
}
```

Comment: _I am not able to find out what's the error with it_ That's a big problem.

Comment: how to pass parameter to oracle function within c# environment ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set CommandType to StoredProcedure - like that:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Thanks... is that best way of getting data or there is better way ?

Comment: It is a way to work with stored procedures. What do you mean be the best way?

Comment: i need to know how to pass parameter to oracle function within c# environment?

Comment: What do you want to archive with that? By the way, there is no significant difference in code between working with Oracle and other database like MSSQL. So most of examples with it will apply to you too (maybe with small changes)