# Does SqlConnection.Dispose() perform a rollback on all pending transactions?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to an uncommitted transaction when the connection is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed)

I know a `SqlTransaction` will rollback itself on `Dispose()` (see [Will a using statement rollback a database transaction if an error occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641660/will-a-using-statement-rollback-a-database-transaction-if-an-error-occurs)), but will it be rolled back when its parent `SqlConnection` is disposed?

Comment: Have you tried it to see?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but I don't think it is handled by SqlConnection class.

I think it's SQL Server that when the connection is closed automatically roll back all not committed  transactions.

Also consider that SqlConnection has a connection pool by default. So it is possible that when you close/dispose a SqlConnection the "real" db connection is still active.

Comment: In fact, the tran will stay open until the connection is reused!