# mysql transaction (commit and rollback)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

below is the code i am using for MySqlTransaction and it is running perfectly....
but problem is as i am using single instance of mysqlcommand i have to use unique PARAMETER in it. which is ruining my query. is there any other way around to do....

i tried to dispose cmd after each query but of no use.. :(

---

```
          con.Open()
            Dim sqlTran As MySqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.Transaction = sqlTran
            Dim str As String = Nothing
            Try
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT myid FROM memaster where    Adate=@adate and ANo=@ano and ASource=@asrc"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adate", txt_bpass_adate.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", txt_bpass_af.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asrc", txt_bpass_asource.Text)
                str = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                'cmd.Dispose()'
                If str Is Nothing Then

                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into memaster (ADate,ANo,ASource) values (@aDate,@aNo,@aSRC)"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", txt_bpass_adate.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aNo", txt_bpass_af.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aSRC", txt_bpass_asource.Text)

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
     sqlTran.Commit()

            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    sqlTran.Rollback()
                Catch ex1 As Exception

                End Try
            End Try
```

---

i actually want to fire  more then 4 queries in single transaction so that if anything go wrong i can rollback it...

if any onebody have any other method of it kindly share the concept wid me...

---

```
     For index As Integer = 1 To 5
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into detail (ID,BNos,SNo) values (@FID1,@BNo,@SeqN1)"
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FID1", str)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BNo", str1)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqN1", txt_bpass_sqn1.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                Next
```

Comment: when you dispose of an instance you cannot use it any more - connection is closed and it is prepared for garbage collection. 
Why you have to use single command instance? I just don't understand your problem try to explain better.

Comment: this.Cmd.Dispose(); would hold good.whats happening when you give dispose()?

Comment: You specify the problem yourself: you're using one `MySqlCommand` when you should be using two.

Comment: @MahaSwetha : actually nothing is happening after disposing it is not even giving an error and i can use the same instance without any problem.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes but i have to use only one....  is there any way actually i have to fire more then 3 queries and have to maintain all in sigle transaction so that if any thing go wrong i can rollback

Comment: @Rafal : hmmm as i said i tried to dispose it but it did not worked... anyways Why i am using single instance because i have to maintained the whole transaction till end so that i can rollback it if any thing go wrong........ Hope you got it now

Comment: @neerajMAX You can execute multiple queries - on separate commands or on the same command - within the same transaction. Why on earth would you be limited to using one `MySqlCommand` instance? And as others have mentioned, you cannot use an object after `Dispose()`-ing it.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: would you share it with me that how i can do it ???  i am actually confused with how will i maintain the "sqlTran" (mentioned in my code) in multiple comands..

Comment: @neerajMAX See my answer as it is too big for a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute multiple commands within the same transaction, ensure that you assign the transaction object to each command individually:

```
Dim selectCmd As MySqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
Dim insertCmd As MySqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()

selectCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ..."
insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT ..."

Dim sqlTran As MySqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
Try
  selectCmd.Transaction = sqlTran
  insertCmd.Transaction = sqlTran

  ...selectCmd.ExecuteScalar()...
  ...insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()...

  sqlTran.Commit()
Catch
  sqlTran.Rollback()
End Try
```

As others have mentioned, it is generally a good idea to `Dispose()` objects (that are `IDisposable`) as soon as you're done working with them. After disposing objects, they can no longer be used.

Comment: @C Evenhuis : okh got it... but have a look on the for loop in my ques what should we have to do for that??? any suggestion???

Answer (score 1):

You can use Using keyword for auto dispose objects.
i don't know VB but I know C#.
Please convert the code into VB.

```
using(MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    using(MysqlTransaction trans=con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //command to executive query
            using(MysqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand("query", con, trans))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parametervalue1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", parametervalue2);
                cmd.ExecutenonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            //command to execute query
            using(MysqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand("query", con, trans))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parametervalue1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", parametervalue2);
                cmd.ExecutenonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            //command to execute query
            using(MysqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand("query", con, trans))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parametervalue1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", parametervalue2);
                cmd.ExecutenonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the failure in insertion is closed for connection purposes, the rollback will not work , will generate exception , have any other way to give Rollback ?

Comment: This is a poor solution - a 'using' statement in c# does a try catch for you, and if anything bad happens MySqlTransaction.cs.Dispose() is called, which rolls back the transaction

Comment: Mario. does MySqlTransaction.cs.Dispose() really roll back the transaction? If that so no need for trans.Rollback() after catch exception, and will the best solution. right?

Comment: this answered me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641660/will-a-using-statement-rollback-a-database-transaction-if-an-error-occurs?rq=1